# What invokes the class initializer method <clinit> and when?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I know that the **new**, **dup**, **invokespecial** and **astore** bytecode patterns will invoke the initializer method `<init>` during class instantiation. What invokes the special `<clinit>`method and when does this happen?

My guess is that `<clinit>` is invoked **before** `<init>` method. Is this documented in the JVM Specification or Java Language Specification?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JVM spec [§2.9. Special Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9):

> A class or interface has at most one class or interface initialization method and is initialized (§5.5) by invoking that method. The initialization method of a class or interface has the special name `<clinit>`, takes no arguments, and is void (§4.3.3).
>
> The name `<clinit>` is supplied by a compiler. Because the name  is not a valid identifier, it cannot be used directly in a program written in the Java programming language. **Class and interface initialization methods are invoked implicitly by the Java Virtual Machine; they are never invoked directly from any Java Virtual Machine instruction, but are invoked only indirectly as part of the class initialization process.**

See [Chapter 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html) for further details on the class initialization process.

Answer (score 7):

The `<clinit>` method is easily seen in class bytecode with bytecode outline tools. It is a static method added by javac and called by JVM after class loading, but only if a class needs static initialization.

```
public class Test1 {
    static int x  = 1; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    }
}

public class Test2 {
    static final int x  = 1; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Test1 has `<clinit>` because its field `x` needs to be initialized with 1; while Test2 has no `<clinit>` method because its `x` is a constant.

It's also interesting to note that `Class.forName` has `boolen intialize` param which determines if the class should be initialized after loading or not.

Comment: "Note that <clinit> is added only if a class needs static initilization" -- any source for that?

Comment: it's from practice (tests) to be honest, also common sense suggests the same, sure theres a paragraph in JLS about it

Answer (score 1):

`<clinit>` are the static initialization blocks for the class, and static field initialization and its invoked by JVM.

Java Spec says,
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#12174

```
The initialization method of a class or interface is static and takes no arguments. It has the special name <clinit>. This name is supplied by a compiler. Because the name <clinit> is not a valid identifier, it cannot be used directly in a program written in the Java programming language. Class and interface initialization methods are invoked implicitly by the Java virtual machine
```